# Verwendung von zögernd und "zögerlich"

Tags: neologism

"zögerlich" ist ein relativ neues Wort, gebräuchlich erst seit den 80ern, wenn man Google glauben darf.

Meines Wissens wird es ausschließlich als Ersatz für das herkömmliche "zögernd" verwendet.

Fragen:

Stimmt das so? Wenn ja, ist ein Grund auszumachen, warum "zögernd" nicht mehr so oft benutzt wird? Gibt es andere Wortpaare X-lich/X-end mit gleicher Bedeutung? Oder ist "zögerlich" eigentlich eine falsche Wortbildung?

Comment: Vielleicht sollte ich eine extra Frage zur Wortbildung stellen, was meint die geschätzte Teilnehmerschaft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zögerlich wird zwar heute viel häufiger verwendet (im gleichen Maße, in dem zögernd weniger verwendet wird), aber ein genauerer Blick offenbart, dass es keineswegs neu ist:

[image: zögerlich 1800-1980]

Dabei ist anzumerken, dass *zögernd* ein Partizip des Verbs *zögern* ist, und wie wir alle wissen, wird sowas Kompliziertes heutzutage immer seltener. ;)

Tatsächlich zeigt der Duden als Bedeutung für *zögerlich* "nur zögernd [durchgeführt]". Auch der Grimm hat jedoch einen Eintrag:

> zögerlich, adj.: diese sache geht sehr zögerlich Steinbach 2, 1099, *nicht üblich geworden*. — dazu unzögerlich, verzögerlich Sanders 1776a: dieser (besitzer eines affen, der ein corpus juris beschädigt hat) bringt alle so wohl verzögerliche als zerstörliche schutzreden (einreden) vor Quistorp an Gottsched bei Danzel 14.

Möglicherweise deutet dies an, dass das Wort relativ lange existiert, sich damals jedoch nicht durchgesetzt hat, was dann erst in der jüngeren Vergangenheit geschah.

Beide Wörterbücher bieten keinen Eintrag für *zögernd*, weil es nur eine Form des Verbs *zögern* ist. Interessant finde ich hierzu eine (aus meiner Sicht nicht belegte) Aussage der unterschiedlichen Bedeutung:

> zögernd =
>
> - unschlüssig,
> - aufschiebend
> - bedächtig
> - stockend
> - pomadig
> - träge
> - antriebsschwach
>
> zögerlich =
>
> - ungern etwas tun, und daher davor zurückweichen
> - ängstlich
> - wachs am
> - misstrauisch
> - unsicher
> - auf der Hut sein
> - vorsichtshalber

Wenn auch ohne Beleg, könnte ich mich mit diesem relativ subtilen Bedeutungsunterschied anfreunden. Auch wenn er natürlich nicht erklärt, warum es eine Verschiebung von zögernd zu zögerlich gibt. Möglicherweise wird heute gerne *zögerlich* für diese Bedeutungen verwendet, wo man früher nur *zögernd* war.

---

Ergänzung: Wie der Zufall mir nur zögernd anvertraute, sah ich just in einem Buch die Formulierung "ich bin zögerlich". Das lässt in mir die Frage aufkommen, ob das Wort "zögernd" hier überhaupt passend wäre oder ob es eigentlich eher als Adverb denn als Adjektiv verwendet wird, während zögerlich hauptsächlich als Adjektiv Verwendung findet. Das passt irgendwie auch, weil es (subjektiv zumindest) eine gewisse Tendenz des Wechsels der Verwendung von Adverbien zu Adjektiven gibt. Aber hier spekuliere ich.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Kann man es vielleicht so zusammenfassen, daß "zögerlich" eine Grundhaltung beschreibt, wohingegen "zögernd" sich auf etwas bestimmtes bezieht, was verzögert wird?

Comment: @Ingo: Ja, ich glaube auch, dass "zögerlich" eben eher als Eigenschaft verwendet wird, während "zögernd" als Adverb bzw. als Qualität einer Tätigkeit verwendet wird.

Answer (score 2):

"Zögerlich" kann man sein, obwohl man gerade nicht "zögert", also auch nicht "zögernd" ist. Es gibt meiner Meinung nach eher eine Eigenschaft einer Person wieder. "Zögernd" hingegen ist ziemlich konkret. Die Person zögert gerade.

Comment: Nach kurzem Zögern muß ich auch deiner Antwort ein +1 geben. Unklar ist mir immer noch die Art der Wortbildung. verb+lich?